# C# 8 Non-Null Reference Types for Database models with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'am trying to implement non-null-reference-types in my project https://dev.to/integerman/safer-code-with-c-8-non-null-reference-types-4f2c. I like it, but have a question regarding database models and constraints.

Is there a way to say that value X is never NULL because it's not nullable in the database?

For example:

```
public class Person
{
      public int Id { get; set; };

      public string Name { get; set; } = "No name set";

      public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } = new List<Dog>();
}
```

Person.Name is nullable=false in the database. Is there a way I can say that this property is never null? Now I have to set a default value.

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Noname";

    public int PersonId {get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Here I wonder the same about Person from Dog. This is a foreign key constraint in the database, A Dog can't exist without an Person(owner). Is there a way to say that; *I know that this value is never null trust me* or something like that ?

[Update]

Is there a way to say that value X is never NULL because it's not nullable in the database?

*Yes, see Pavel Anikhouski answer*

Should you do it:

*No, see TomTom s answer*

The best solution I think is @canton7 last comment. He links to this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization

Another reason:

```
public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } = new List<Dog>();
```

If you are trying to get a Person like this:

```
var person = _dbcontext.persons.Single(x => x.Name == "John").ToList(); 
Console.log($"John has {person.Dogs.Count} dogs")
```

This will output 0 everytime, because we forgot to .Include(x => x.dogs).
So it's wrong.

Comment: You can also forcibly initialize those properties to null: `{ get; set; } = null!;`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have already set <Nullable>enable</Nullable> in the project file. So that won't help

Comment: if you are using code first approach, add attribute `[Required]` to the property where you don't want null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!` for that

```cs
public Person Person { get; set; } = default!;
```

As it pointed in comments, you should carefully use it, since it works with any type (value or reference one) and you can use `null!` as well

Comment: `default!` should be used with care. The benefit is that it works for any type (and/or "reads nice"); the *drawback* is that it works for any type. `int i { get; set; } = default!;` is legal, but pointless; `int i { get; set; } = null!;` is not legal, and helps signal that you may be laboring under the mistaken belief that something is nullable when it's not.

Answer (score 5):

No, and it makes no sense. Particularly in the area of database entities - you MUST allow null because otherwise you can not load the object without automatically loading the related object. Which ultimately will force you to load a lot of data that you may not want for a simple query.

Dogs CAN exist without Person. Not on db level, but I can ask for a list of all dogs and not be interested in the owners at this point.

Comment: Probably his business asks all dogs belongs to persons.

Comment: That is not the point. Those are database access objects. You can load dogs i.e. to see the names of dogs without loading the owners. THis is why I say in the db it is ok to ahve integrity, but the poitners are nullable. The "null enforcement" does not play nice with database objects where the loading may be dependent on usage, not on integrity.